# Writing to internal textblock is slower than writing to external .txt file

Tags: python

Writing 20million entries to Blenders internal textblock takes 38sec.
Wiriting to an external .txt file takes 29sec.

```
import bpy
import time

tb = bpy.data.texts.new("text_block")
txt = open(bpy.path.abspath("//")+"vertex_data.txt", "w")
then = time.time()

for i in range(20000000):
    tb.write(str(i)+"\n")
    #txt.write(str(i)+"\n")

#txt.close()

now = time.time()
print(now-then)
```

I like to keep the custom data in the internal textblock of Blender,
is there a way to speed this up?

Comment: Imagine   `tb.write("\n".join(map(str,range(2000))))` would be quicker in both instances.

Comment: That worked, time is down from 38sec to 16sec. What is the trick here?

Comment: Writing only once. Also see [String addition - this is the slowest option, don’t use if you can help it, especially when writing data in a loop.](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_best_practice.html#writing-strings-to-a-file-python-general)